# Was JFrame disposed?

Tags: java, swing, jframe

I've got an application with several `JFrame` window.

My main `JFrame` wants to know if another `JFrame` is already disposed.

Which method shall I call to decide?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Although you should probably avoid [the use of multiple `JFrame`s](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9554636/the-use-of-multiple-jframes-good-bad-practice/9554657#9554657), [`isDisplayable()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/Component.html#isDisplayable%28%29) is a method you could use for this.

Example:

[image]

```
import java.awt.EventQueue;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;

import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JPanel;

public class Example {

    public Example() {
        JFrame frame = new JFrame("Frame 1");
        JFrame frame2 = new JFrame("Frame 2");

        JLabel label = new JLabel("");

        JButton button = new JButton("Check");
        button.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                label.setText(frame2.isDisplayable() ? "Active" : "Disposed");
            }
        });

        JPanel panel = new JPanel();
        panel.add(button);
        panel.add(label);

        frame.setContentPane(panel);
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.setSize(200, 100);
        frame.setVisible(true);

        frame2.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);
        frame2.setSize(200, 100);
        frame2.setLocation(frame.getX() + frame.getWidth(), frame.getY());
        frame2.setVisible(true);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                new Example();
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You will want to use a [WindowListener](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/events/windowlistener.html) to check if it is disposed.

Comment: I don't want to be notified if it is disposed. I just want to check at a certain point.